# In a multiplicative group G, given that we have defined $x^n$ for $x \epsilon G$ and n is a positive integer

Tags: abstract-algebra

In a multiplicative group G, given that we have defined $x^n$ for $x \epsilon G$ and n is a positive integer, how should we define $x^n$ if n is a negative integer?

So i know $(gh)^n = g^n h^n$
for all g, h ∈ G says that the nth power map G → G, where $ g → g^n$, is a homomorphism from G to itself when n is an integer( negative, positive or 0)

but i dont know how to relate this to a multiplicative group. would that be using $g^{m+n}= g^m g^n$??

Comment: Yes, it follows from the desired relation $g^0 = g^{n+-n} = g^ng^{-n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a negative integer $-n$, it is $(x^{-1})^n$ where $x^{-1}$ is the inverse of $x$.